# Ayuda con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Requiero un poco de orientación y ojala ustedes puedan ayudarme, tengo un proyecto hecho en CI 2, el cual le paga el sueldo a un empleado de forma mensual, el problema que presento es que si una persona entra a trabajar después de pagarse los sueldos, el sueldo de él se pagaría hasta el próximo pago del siguiente mes, tengo problemas para calcular el sueldo complementario del mes en el que entró el empleado y que ese complemento se sume al sueldo del mes próximo, creo que el problema esta en el `ELSE` creo que debe de ser como esta formateada la fecha, si alguien sabe como puedo hacerle para que el código calcule los días trabajados desde que se dio de alta el empleado hasta el día ultimo del mes les agradeceré (nota: en mi proyecto todos los meses del año tienen 30 días)

```
$alta = strtotime($comisionista->fecha_ingreso);    

if ($fecha_ultimo_pago != NULL && $alta >= $fecha_ultimo_pago) {

                $dias = 0;
                //Para descontar dias
                if (date('Y-m', $alta) == date('Y-m'))
                    $dias = -1 * ($alta - strtotime(date('Y-m-1'))) / (60 * 60 * 24);
                else
                {
                    $dias = (strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) date('n'), 1, date('Y')) - $alta )) / (60 * 60 * 24);

                    $monthbefore = strtotime(mktime(0, 0, 0,  ((int) date('m')-1), 1, date('Y')));

                    $diasma = date ('t',$monthbefore );
                    if($diasma > 30)
                        $dias = $dias-1;                        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías jugar con las opciones de añadir fechas en strtotime(), algo asi:

```
$alta = strtotime($comisionista->fecha_ingreso);    
if ($fecha_ultimo_pago != NULL && $alta >= $fecha_ultimo_pago) {
    $dias = 0;
    $diasrestantes = $alta; // para que sea el comparador
    while (date('Y-m-d',$diasrestantes) < date('Y-m-d')) {
        $dias++;
        $diasrestantes = strtotime('+1 day', $diasrestantes);
    }
    echo $dias;//solamente como prueba
}
```

Comment: Hice algo muy parecido y de hecho ya pude corregirlo, aun asi muchas gracias ....